# 3rd Party .Net Assembly not working in WebService project

Tags: c#, assemblies, web-config, asmx, app-config

So I'm trying to use a .Net Assembly in my web services project.  This assembly requires lots of settings in App.config.  But my web service doesn't have an App.config, it has a web.config.  It seems that it uses sections that an app.config would have that don't even exist for web projects.  Is there any way I can make this assembly work? (make it read another config file maybe?)

Comment: Can you just add those sections to the web.config?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use the same configuration sections in the `web.config` file that exist in the `app.config` and it would work.

The way the configuration subsystem works means that it does not matter.

Comment: From what I can tell that's not the case.  web.config doesn't really have appSettings, so if the dll is dependent on those it can't read them using the standard ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.

Comment: @flxkid - Have you tried? I have definitely used `appSettings` sections in `web.config` before without any problems.